# Pandas: Group data into seperate parts based on a targetted sample size

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split a pandas dataframe into distinct groups based on the value of a column with a targetted sample size. Example of a dataframe below:

```
Rating     Result
1           25
2           24
5           20
5           21
6           18
7           20
```

Assume I would like to split the above dataframe into distinct categories so that each group contained 2 rows of values and it would be seperated based on the value of the Rating.

So the first 2 rows has the 2 lowest ratings which would put them in their own group. The 5 and 5 rating is in the 2nd group and the 6 and 7 rating is in the 3rd and last groups.

This would then allow me to look up what the average result is for the different groups of ratings.

The way I am currently trying to adress this task atm is through a primitive loop where I have hardcoded some initial values and then I expand the range of the parameters with a set amount until I am reaching the desired sample size. Example below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Rating','Result'],data=[[1,25], [2,24], [5,20], [5,21], [6,18], [7,20]])

initial_rating_threshold = [2,4,6]
targetted_sample_size = 2
paramter_change = 1
for loop_number,original_threshold in enumerate(initial_rating_threshold):
min_threshold = original_threshold-paramter_change*loop_number-2
max_threshold = original_threshold + paramter_change * loop_number
count = len(df.loc[(df['Rating'] >= min_threshold) & (df['Rating'] < max_threshold )])

if count >=targetted_sample_size:
    break
    # This filter provides the dataframe with minimum desired sample size
```

The above code kinda does the job, however I simplified it a bit and made it adjust both the min parameter value and max parameter value at the same time.

Is there anyway to perform the above code in a more efficient manner? Ideally it could also handle more columns than 1 and without any hardcoding.